# Clone new objects to pass to ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, events

I'm building an android app and I was trying to add objects to an `ArrayList`. I thought this would create a copy of the object in `ArrayList` and then I could reuse the object. I've realized this isn't the case and that `ArryList` was actually referencing the original object.

I'm not really sure how I'd use a loop to create new objects in the `onCreate` function so do I somehow need to clone the object and pass it to the `ArrayList`?

Anyway here's my code:

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
  private Item myItem = new Item();

  btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alItems.add(myItem);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [`copy constructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749218/building-a-copy-constructor-in-java) in your `Item` class, and use it to create a copy of your object.

```
public class Item {
    private int field1;
    public Item() { }

    public Item(Item item) {
       this.field1 = item.field1;
    }
}
```

And add your object to list using: -

```
alItems.add(new Item(myItem));
```

Comment: Brilliant didn't know about copy constructors and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 2):

Make your `Item` implement `Clonable` then

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        alItems.add(myItem.clone());
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: A copy constructor is a better way to go than using `clone` method. Take a look at `Effective Java - Item # 11`

Comment: @RohitJain I'v used copy constructor in my environment but migrated to cloning and it had greatly simplified the implementation.